# Type String is not assignable to 'never' Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Getting an `error TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'`
I was trying to assign 4 fields on those 4 fields error TS2322 was showing

1. 'objectId': current.objectId
2. 'locationName': loc.locationName
3. 'attributeName': attr.attributeName,
4. 'attributeValue': attr.attributeValue

```
parseResponse(objects: empDetails): any {
    return objects?.empList?.reduce((data, current: empList) => {
      current?.locationDetails?.forEach(loc=> {
        loc?.attributeDetails?.forEach(attr => {
          data.push({
 'objectId': current.objectId, 'locationName': loc.locationName, 'attributeName': attr.attributeName, 'attributeValue': attr.attributeValue
          });
        });
      });
      return data;
    }, []);
  }
```

Comment: What does your type `empDetails` and `empList` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define data :

```
const data = [];
data.push({
 'objectId': current.objectId, 'locationName': loc.locationName, 'attributeName': attr.attributeName, 'attributeValue': attr.attributeValue
          });
        });
      });
```